# JavaScript function undefined error onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to stack paragraphs on top of each other. And when I mouseover, I want that particular paragraph to show up. But I am getting errors:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

JS:

```
var topLayer = "p3";


function moveIt(toTop)
{
    var oldTop = document.getElementById(topLayer).style;
    var newTop = document.getElementById(toTop).style;

    oldTop.z-index = "0";
    newTop.z-index = "10";

    topLayer = document.getElementById(toTop).id;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text of Stacked Paragraph</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stacked.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="stacked.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="p1" class="para1" onmouseover="moveIt('p1')">
        This is one of the paragraphs. 
    </p>
    <p id="p2" class="para2" onmouseover="moveIt('p2')">
        Another paragraph.
    </p>
    <p id="p3" class="para3" onmouseover="moveIt('p3')">
        More paragraph.
    </p>
</body>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is `moveIt` defined?

Comment: which line? Have you checked in Chrome Inspector? Is `oldTop.z-index` valid syntax?

Comment: From Webmasters StackExchange: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: @TJ- yes, its giving showing me the 9th line...

Comment: @TJ- the one you commented `oldTop.z-index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DOM element's `z-index` property is set via `zIndex`:

```
var topLayer = "p3";

function moveIt(toTop) {
    var oldTop = document.getElementById(topLayer).style;
    var newTop = document.getElementById(toTop).style;

    oldTop.zIndex = "0";
    newTop.zIndex = "10";

    topLayer = document.getElementById(toTop).id;
}
```

Jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/d4LLfs6e/1/

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear it!